# Identifying and manipulating objects in images on android

Tags: android, image-processing

I am trying to develop a visual cryptography android application. The idea is that a user can take a photo of a share which just looks like a rectangle of black and white dots. The application should then be able to overlay a second image of a share on the one found in the picture taken through the camera to reveal a secret.

I currently have an application that takes a picture and is able to overlay a second share on top of that picture but I cant tell if that picture contains a share in the first place how can I identify and find the location of a share in a image.

Is there a way to alter a open source qr scanner for my purpose as a QR code an a visual cryptography share look similar?

An example of visual cryptography shares can be found here (i couldn't post images due to no reputation):

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Visual_crypto_animation_demo.gif

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) for image processing. It has a lot of features included you want.

If you are going tu use it in android, there is a wrapper in java you can use: [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/)